# Beginner Level PLC Programming / Simulation and Configuration

Tags: plc

I am a beginner in PLC programming and just started to learn by self.

Is there any simulation software for PLC in Windows?

Do we have a PLC that works on 5 volts DC power supply?

Actually for a Industrial project I need to control the following:

```
1. Dispense Liquid
2. Store Data (ID Number probably a storage device)
3. Send Data to Web Server
4. Be placed in remote Village (device to be placed under scorching sun)
5. Sensors - flow, level, solenoid valve and a couple of more
6. A Graphical Dashboard
7. RFID authentication (offline - based upon a logic)
8. Buzzer
```

and maybe a couple of more.

What PLC configuration should be applicable for my project.

Comment: This is way off-topic for SO.

Comment: @Prakash: you seem to be posting a lot of off-topic questions lately. Some of these would be on-topic for http://electronics.stackexchange.com though, so I suggest taking a look there and perhaps migrating questions about PLCs, micro-controllers, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Paul I accept my posting as inaccurate and would post in right group

Answer (score -1):

For beginner's simulator look at LogixPro which emulates Rslogix 500 Allen Bradley software package.

Also rslogix micro, and emulate 500 from Rockwell Automation is free to download.

I doubt there's any industrial plc that runs on 5v, although I could be wrong. You might be looking for a microcontroller.

Your project might seem way out of your league, start with the basics. 
A good book for plc beginner's for free is Automating manufacturing systems by Hugh Jack.

I hope that get you in the right track.